# Any way to get categoryId using Youtube v3 search API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

Went through the youtube [search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to search for videos/playlists/channels for a searchTerm. The results/items returned doesn't contain categoryId as part of `snippet`. But the [API for videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) does return categoryId in items but doesn't provide a way to search for a term.

Is there any way or I have to first search the videos using the `search` call and then pass all videoIds to `videos` call to get the categoryIds for each ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the latter ... the API is designed with the paradigm that the search endpoint just return minimal data (i.e. "search results"), and then the second call for a single ID or a batched call gets details (in some ways it makes sense; the old API had thousands of developers getting entire feeds for just a tiny bit of used data ... this approach pushes the burden onto the developers more to be economical with the calls they make, the fields they return, etc.). But there are use cases where this just causes frustrating overhead for devs ...

Comment: thanks for confirming.